# How to run several looping functions at the same time in python?

Tags: python, function, loops, while-loop

i've been working on a project that i was assigned to do. it is about some sort of parking lot where the cars that enter, are generated automaticly (done) now, I've put them into a 'waiting list (because i have to represent them with a GUI module later) in order to later be assigned in a spot in the parking lot. and then they must get out the parking lot (also randomly)

The problem raises when I created a function that will always create cars randomly, now i cant call any other function because the first one is looping.

the question is, is there a way to call several looping functions at the same time?

Thanks

Comment: Try using the threading module http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html. But beware of the GIL  http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Comment: There is no particular reason to "beware of the GIL" unless the whole simulation is CPU bound.  For the most part, threading works great for simulations such as the parking lot problem.

Answer (score 1):

> the question is, is there a way to call several looping functions at the same time?

This is a great question and there are several ways to do it.

[Threading](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html#module-threading) can let your functions run concurrently.  The data flow between the threads should be managed using the [Queue module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/queue.html#module-Queue):

```
# Inter-thread communication
wait_to_park = Queue()
wait_to_exit = Queue()

# Start the simulation
tg = threading.Thread(target=generate_cars)
tp = threading.Thread(target=park_cars)
tu = threading.Thread(target=unpark_cars)
tg.start(); tp.start(); tu.start()

# Wait for simumlation to finish
tg.join()
wait_to_park.join()
tp.join()
wait_to_exit.join()
tu.join()
```

Alternatively, you can use an event-loop such as the [sched module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sched.html#module-sched) to coordinate the events.   [Generators](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html#generators) may help with this -- they work like functions that can be suspended and restarted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Raymond! i've been trying to figure it out since i would like to learn how to use this thread module.
in the code the you suggested as example, the wait_to_park, wait_to_exit, generate_cars and so, are previeusly declared functions right?

Answer (score 0):

maybe import `random` and then set up a range that you want certain events to happen?

```
def mainLoop():
   while True:
      x = random.randrange(1,100)
      if 0>x>10: do something()
      if 10>x>60: do somethingMoreFrequently()
      if 60>x>61: do somethingRarely()
```

etcetera

if you LITERALLY want to call several looping functions at the same time be prepared to learn about Threading. Threading is difficult and i never do it unless 100% necessary.

but this should be simple enough to achieve without

Answer (score 0):

Don't have both infinitely loop, have then each do work if needed and return (or possibly yield).  Then have your main event loop call both.  Something like this:

```
def car_arrival():
    if need_to_generate_car:
        # do car generation stuff
    return

def car_departure()
   if time_for_car_to_leave:
       # do car leaving stuff
   return


def event_loop():
    while sim_running:
        car_arrival()
        car_departure()
        sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks! i think i'll give this a try.The thing is that if the functions that randomly sets the hour in the future for the next car happens to create the next one in 0 seconds and if the whole while cycle is not finished by then, the program will never eventually create the car. However, i think i can fix that particular situtation :) thanks!